# set minute 00 in datetimepicker (Example 27-02-2019 15:00)

Tags: yii2, datetimepicker

I am new to yii2, can anybody know how to set minute 00 in datetimepicker in yii2 ??

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'start_date')->widget(DateTimePicker::classname(), ['options' => ['placeholder' => 'Choose Strating Date..'],
                        'pluginOptions' => [
                          'format' => 'dd-mm-yyyy hh:ii',
                          'autoclose' => true,
                          'minView' => 1,
                          'minute' => 00,
                          'startDate' => date('d-m-Y H:i'),
                          'hoursDisabled' => [0,1,2,3,4,5,6],
                        ]])->label(false); ?>
```

Comment: `date('d-m-Y H:00')`?

Comment: not working, It shows 27-03-2019 10:51 not 27-03-2019 10:00

Comment: Did you check the documentation?
http://demos.krajee.com/widget-details/datetimepicker#markup-input

Comment: yes, I did but it not mention anywhere

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have research and got the answer by doing this

```
'format' => 'dd-mm-yy hh:00',
'startDate' => date("d-m-y h"),
```

in plugin option but this is not fully satisfied because after doing this datetime picker will not highlight selected date so I am still looking for better solution.

Answer (score 1):

Define `$model->start_date` value

```
$model->start_date = date('d-m-Y H:00');
```

and set `startDate` in format `Y-m-d`

```
['pluginOptions']['startDate'] = date('Y-m-d');
```

You may read [doc of Bootstrap DateTimePicker](https://www.malot.fr/bootstrap-datetimepicker/) plugin for more.

Comment: Thanks for reply , after doing this datetime picker will not highlight selected date so I am still looking for better solution.